# Random (well, apparently) "IndexError: list index out of range"

Tags: python, xml

I am trying to write a programme that parses all the xml files within a single directory. The code seems to work OK, but sometimes a file is parsed without any trouble (when it is alone or when it is the first one to be parsed), sometimes parsing the same file returns ""IndexError: list index out of range"

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse, parseString
import os

liste=open('oup_list_hybrid.txt','a')
for r,d,f in os.walk('C:/Users/bober/Documents/Analyse_citation_crossref/'):
    for files in f:
        if files.endswith(".xml"):
            print files
            dom=parse(files)
            for element in dom.getElementsByTagName('record'):
                rights = element.getElementsByTagName('dc:rights')
                doi = element.getElementsByTagName('dc:identifier')
                date= element.getElementsByTagName('dc:date')
                try:
                    valeurrights=rights[0].firstChild.nodeValue
                    valeurdoi=doi[1].firstChild.nodeValue
                    valeurdate=date[0].firstChild.nodeValue
                    resultat=valeurrights+';'+valeurdoi+';'+valeurdate+'\n'
                    liste.write(resultat)
                except IndexError:
                    print 'pb avec'+files
                    continue


    break
liste.close()
```

What am I doing wrong here ?
Thanks in advance for any help !

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post the full trace of your error?

Comment: If there is an index error, either the tag in question was not found at all, or only one was found (in the case of `doi`). Without the XML file or traceback this is impossible to narrow down to more specific information.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. Here is the trace of the error <code>line 14, in <module>
    resultat=rights[0].firstChild.nodeValue+';'+doi[0].firstChild.nodeValue+';'+date[0].firstChild.nodeValue+'\n'
IndexError: list index out of range</code>, and here is the xml file I have a problem with : http://pastebin.com/9F6gr87D

Comment: And my main problem is that when this file is first in a row, it is parsed and returns no error, otherwise I have an IndexError

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that `rights`, `doi` or `date` actually contain anything? If the `getElementsByTagName` doesn't find anything, these lists will be empty.

`doi` may also only contain one element, and you're trying to access the second `doi[1]`.

Long story short, check your lists actually contain data before accessing it, or use a `try-catch`

Comment: Hi thanks. I updated my code and handle the errors now. I can now spot  the files that return an error, but I can't figure out why there is an error (rights, doi and date always contain something)

Comment: Well, among my list of 8275 XML files some of them have empty <record></record>, so that's the reason why something went wrong in the first place and handling errors helped a lot. Nevertheless, I just can't figure out why the order in which the files a parsed seems to matter. Once again thx everybody for your help.

Comment: Either way, never assume anything. Glad to help.